# Unfortunately Sunshine app is not working

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I was just going through udacity sunshine app and I not able to resolve this problem i.e. after adding the openweather api the app is not working it just shows "Unfortunately Sunshine app is not working"

the MainActivity.java file is as follow:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the MainActivityFragment.java file is as follow:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

   String[] forecastArray={
            "Today-Sunny-88/63",
            "Tomorrow-Foggy-70/40",
            "Weds-Cloudy-72/63",
            "Thurs-Asteroids-75/65",
            "Fri-Heavy Rain-65/56",
            "Sat-HELP-60/51",
            "Sun-Sunny-80/68"
    };

    List<String> weekForecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);
    ListView lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
    lv.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;


    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String forecastJsonStr = null;


    try {
        // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
        // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
        // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
        URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=d0657975451a7efca018097b88c4d975");


        // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();


        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }
        forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
        // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
        // to parse it.
        return null;
    } finally{
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return rootView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `runOnUiThread` or even `AsyncTask`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // your codes

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In android you cannot make network calls on the UI thread.

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=d0657975451a7efca018097b88c4d975");
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //This causes an exception
```

You must run these and any code for network operations in a background thread, using `AsyncTask` or even a `Runnable` passed to a `Thread` or `Executor`.